# How to use an image in R5RS

Tags: image, scheme, jpeg, r5rs, racket

I'm looking for a way to import a .jpg file into R5RS. I would like to use it as background for a game that I'm making.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Many Scheme implementations have support for image files. The R5RS standard, as written, does not. I suggest using Racket, where you can use, e.g.,

```
(require 2htdp/image)
(bitmap/file "/path/to/foo.jpg")
```

In fact, there are *many* parts of building a game that are not going to fit well under the R5RS umbrella. I'm afraid you're almost certainly going to have to pick an implementation, and use features that lie outside of the standard.

Answer (score 0):

I use the graphics/graphics library.
Put it in your file by using this (in racket):

```
(require graphics/graphics)
```

This is the usage:

```
((draw-pixmap viewport) file p [color]) → void?
  viewport : viewport?
  file : path-string?
  p : posn?
  color : (or/c (integer-in 0 299)
                string?
                rgb?)
```

You can find more help in the [Racket documentation](http://download.racket-lang.org/docs/5.0.1/html/graphics/Draw__Clear__and_Flip_Operations.html#%28part._.Pixmaps%29)